# Context for nested classes in ES6 is strange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, webpack

I have the following nested class structure:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextField} from '@material-ui/core';
import './ProfileEditor.css';

export default class ProfileEditor extends Component {
    SyncedTextField = class SyncedTextField extends Component {
        onChange = event => {
            console.log(this);
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <TextField
                    {...this.props}
                    onChange={this.onChange}/>
            );
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form className={"ProfileEditor"}>
                <this.SyncedTextField/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

When the code is bundled by Webpack, and run in Firefox, it runs `this.onChange` correctly, but the outputted `this` refers the the context of the `ProfileEditor` class instead.

This is excessively strange because in the JSX, when I refer to "this" it points to SyncedTextField correctly, but in the onChange method, it points to `ProfileEditor`.

I did add some properties to `ProfileEditor` to sanity check myself, and the properties showed up as declared in `ProfileEditor`, even when a conflicting definition was provided in SyncedTextField.

Can someone please tell me how I can avoid this issue, and what may be causing it?

Comment: Same thing happens when tested in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: yes, that's right - because it's an arrow function ... whose `this` is not the same as if the function were the regular notation (i.e. how you did `render()`)

Comment: Oh, so the arrow function would remain bound to the `ProfileEditor` scope, not the `SyncedTextField`? Seems kinda strange to me, but thanks!

Comment: it's got to do with what `this` is at the time the function is defined or something - I'm horrible at explaining arrow functions :p is there any reason you can't `onChange(event) {` ... etc?

Comment: No, there isn't, I was just experimenting with what the context would be, and the results really surprised me. I think it may be because `class` is internally a fancier way to provide a function with a prototype, which I saw when I logged it.

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect behaviour may be specific to browser development tools. But in this case it's caused by how transpiler works. There is a bug in Babel 6 class fields (which are stage 3 proposal) transform implementation.

[The example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6sh7dt) compiled with Babel outputs `ProfileEditor` as `this` in `onChange`.

Here's `SyncedTextField` constructor from Babel output:

```
function SyncedTextField() {
  var _ref2;

  var _temp2, _this2, _ret2;

  _classCallCheck(this, SyncedTextField);

  for (
    var _len2 = arguments.length, args = Array(_len2), _key2 = 0;
    _key2 < _len2;
    _key2++
  ) {
    args[_key2] = arguments[_key2];
  }

  return (
    (_ret2 = ((_temp2 = ((_this2 = _possibleConstructorReturn(
      this,
      (_ref2 =
        SyncedTextField.__proto__ ||
        Object.getPrototypeOf(SyncedTextField)).call.apply(
        _ref2,
        [this].concat(args)
      )
    )),
    _this2)),
    (_this2.onChange = function(event) {
      console.log(_this); // SHOULD BE _this2
    }),
    _temp2)),
    _possibleConstructorReturn(_this2, _ret2)
  );
}
```

Notice that transpilers create `_this`, `_this2`, etc. temporary variables to provide lexical `this` in arrow functions but Babel uses wrong variable.

`onChange = ...` class field is syntactic sugar for:

```
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.onChange = event => {
        console.log(this);
    };
  }
```

When [the example is changed from class fields to constructor code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zbfxsh), it outputs `SyncedTextField`.

[The same example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h7rsgm) compiled with TypeScript (used by Stackblitz by default in React template) works as expected and outputs `SyncedTextField` as `this` in `onChange`.

**Since classes are rarely defined this way, Babel bug is usually not applicable.**

`SyncedTextField = class SyncedTextField extends Component {...}` is an antipattern. There is no reason to nest class expression like that. It is inefficient because it is evaluated on each `ProfileEditor` instantiation. It should be class declaration, can be used as `<SyncedTextField/> this way.`

Even if `SyncedTextField` should be defined as a property of `ProfileEditor` component for testability or extensibility reasons, it's preferable to make it prototype property:

```
class SyncedTextField extends Component {...}

class ProfileEditor extends Component {
  get SyncedTextField() { return SyncedTextField }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer. Does Create React App automatically add Babel? As a side note, I didn't want to extract SyncedTextField because it managed the `ProfileEditor`'s state.

Comment: create-react-app is just CLI tool to set up https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts/template Webpack+Babel template. So yes, it uses Babel. I would expect this problem to be fixed in Babel 7, so you could eject the project and upgrade Babel to 7. *because it managed the ProfileEditor's state* - this isn't shown in the question. It's very likely that there are more idiomatic ways to do what you're trying to do. Consider asking a question if needed.