# Do React or Next.js Internally Clean Class Properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class, next.js

In the code provided below I am able to see `this.mBaseService` is defined above the first `debugger` but not below the second `debugger`.

Is anyone able to explain why this is the case? One theory I had is that React or Next.js may be internally clearing properties.

```
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

    import ReactDropzone from 'react-dropzone';
    import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Jumbotron, ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'reactstrap';

    import DefaultHomeView from '../components/default-home-view';
    import Page from '../components/page';
    import EteeReport from '../components/etee-report';
    import Layout from '../components/layout';
    import { ServiceBaseService } from '../services/service-base/service-base.service';

    export default class extends Page {
        mBaseService = new ServiceBaseService();

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                files: [],
            };

            console.log('it exists!', this.mBaseService);
            debugger;
            //this.mBaseService = new ServiceBaseService();
        }

        fHandleOnDrop = async files => {
            debugger;
            const oResponse = await this.mBaseService.fpPost('/reports', {
                oDataToPost: JSON.stringify(files),
            });

            // TODO: if valid csv then parse and chart the data
            this.setState({
                files: this.state.files.concat(files),
            });
        };

        fClearFiles = () => {
            this.setState({
                files: [],
            });
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <Layout {...this.props} navmenu={false} container={false}>
                    {!this.state.files.length && (
                        <DefaultHomeView {...this.props} fHandleOnDrop={this.fHandleOnDrop} files={this.state.files} />
                    )}
                    {this.state.files.length && <EteeReport {...this.props} {...this.state} fClearFiles={this.fClearFiles} />}
                </Layout>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you `console.log(this.mBaseService)` in either the constructor or in `fHandleOnDrop` I think you will see that's it's accessible in both places. I'm not sure why you can't see it in the debugger though.

Comment: That's true. Weird. If I call `console.log(this.mBaseService)` in `fHandleOnDrop` I see the expected result, even though if I'm in dev tools and I log `this.mBaseService` to console it comes as undefined. I'd still like to know *why*, but I'll close if recommended.

Comment: @Tholle this answers a second question I had also. You see how this `class extends Page`? Well, `Page` also has `mBaseService = new ServiceBaseService();`, but it wasn't showing for me when debugging. Now if I comment that property on the child class and I `console.log` I can see it, even though if I `debugger` and interrogate on the console it's undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is likely specific to how the code is transpiled with Babel. As explained in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51652054/3731501), class fields (arrow methods) are transpiled to constructor code and `this` is replaced with `_this`, `_this2`, etc. temporary variables where needed to mimic the behaviour of lexical `this` in arrows.

A property may not be available on `this` in debugger but on temporary `_this?` variable which is considered proper context in original code.

In this specific case this is caused by the fact that `fHandleOnDrop` is passed as callback:

```
<DefaultHomeView {...this.props} fHandleOnDrop={this.fHandleOnDrop} files={this.state.files} />
```

This means `this.props.fHandleOnDrop()` has been dereferenced and is being called with wrong `this` , while the function uses `_this?` variable internally to refer to proper context:

```
    fHandleOnDrop = async files => {
        console.log(this.mBaseService) // should be ok
        eval('console.log(this.mBaseService)') // should fail
```

This likely wouldn't be the case if Babel was configured to not transpile arrows to ES5 target by not using `es2015` preset.

Regardless of these concerns, there is always a chance that this behaviour is specific to particular development tools.

Comment: Thanks! Not only did you answer the question but you also provided a workaround...which I wasn't even sure was possible