# React TypeError: _this.props. ... is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend

i am currently working on creating email password request with mailtrap, i get the email, but app crashs, i tried to catch error but it didnt work. I am losing my mind over this

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZSRf.png)

```html
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Message } from "semantic-ui-react";
import ForgotPasswordForm from "../forms/ForgotPasswordForm";
import { resetPasswordRequest } from "../../actions/auth";

class ForgotPasswordPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    success: false
  };

  submit = data =>
    this.props
      .resetPasswordRequest(data)
      .then(() => this.setState({ success: true }));

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.success ? (
          <Message>Email has been sent.</Message>
        ) : (
          <ForgotPasswordForm submit={this.submit} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ForgotPasswordPage.propTypes = {
  resetPasswordRequest: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { resetPasswordRequest }
)(ForgotPasswordPage);
```

```html
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Form, Button, Message } from "semantic-ui-react";
import isEmail from "validator/lib/isEmail";
import InLineError from "../messages/InLineError";

class ForgotPasswordForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: {
      email: ""
    },
    loading: false,
    errors: {}
  };

  onChange = e =>
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      data: { ...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    });

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const errors = this.validate(this.state.data);
    this.setState({ errors });
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      this.props
        .submit(this.state.data)
        .catch(err =>
          this.setState({ errors: err.response.data.errors, loading: false })
        );
    }
  };

  validate = data => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!isEmail(data.email)) errors.email = "Invalid email";
    return errors;
  };

  render() {
    const { errors, data, loading } = this.state;

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} loading={loading}>
        {!!errors.global && <Message negative>{errors.global}</Message>}
        <Form.Field error={!!errors.email}>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="email"
            value={data.email}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          {errors.email && <InLineError text={errors.email} />}
        </Form.Field>
        <Button primary>ForgotPasswordForm</Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

ForgotPasswordForm.propTypes = {
  submit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default ForgotPasswordForm;
```

Code after this is okey, but its keep crashing at submit for no clear reason for me

*Am if number no up period regard sudden better. Decisively surrounded all admiration and not you. Out particular sympathize not favourable introduced insipidity but*

Comment: Did you try just with regular function bindings? ```function submit(){}``` out of your class, and in the constructor ```this.submit = submit.bind(this)```? Looks like it might be losing the reference to ```this```, no sure though, I have not used public class fields, so IDK how the bindings work with it.

Comment: @galileopy `bind` is not needed because there's an arrow.

Comment: There's no evidence that `resetPasswordRequest` import is defined. I'd expect it's not because it seems there are no other possible problems.

Comment: @estus oh, so arrows in public fields get bound automagically? that's neat.

Comment: @galileopy Yes, that's the idea. The coin has two sides, I'd generally go with `bind`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882417/3731501 . Also, class fields are pretty much messed up in Babel, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51652054/3731501

Comment: thank you all, i am new to react, there is no problem with functionality its does job done, but after it send email, app shows that error, i tried error boundary but it didnt help me

Comment: and it shows diffrent kind of error in chrome[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdlsn.png

Comment: @J.Duie The error means that resetPasswordRequest doesn't return a promise. The question doesn't contain resetPasswordRequest. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Consider using `@` in order for users to get a notification.

Comment: @estus okey i implemented that in a different way, reduced some of the possibilities. but the problem is coming up again appears on another place in code.

Comment: When i delete .then and .catch it does work with no problem, but i cant update my states, it always work with single func call  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQGCH.png

Comment: It's unclear what exactly the problem is now. Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case, this is a requirement for code-related questions. You can debug your own app. Others cannot. All code and errors should be specified as text in question body, not as images.