# Trying to access "this.state" in chrome Sources tab. I get undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging

I'm new to React.
I'm currently studying react from a youtube video called "The Net Ninja" "Complete React Tutorial (& Redux)".
on the tutorial, nothing is mentioned about debugging in chrome (yet).
I had a bug (same Key for 2 child elements) with adding a new UI component to a list of the same components.
Now I use arrow function to auto bind "this".
yet in the chrome debugger, I can't watch "this.state" cuz "this" is undefined. the real bug is that in code line like "if(this.state.id)" it's always false - cuz "this" undefined. 
but if I do code line like "let a = this.state" I can watch "a" with all the data that "this.state" has. 
her some of my code and some photos from the debugger.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Ninjas from './Ninjas';
import AddNinja from './AddNinja';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    ninjas: [
      { name: 'Ryu', age: 30, belt: 'black', id: 1 },
      { name: 'Yoshi', age: 20, belt: 'green', id: 2 },
      { name: 'Crystal', age: 25, belt: 'blue', id: 3 }
    ]
  }

  addNinja = (ninja) => {
    ninja.id = Math.random();
    let ninjas = [...this.state.ninjas, ninja];
    this.setState({
      ninjas: ninjas
    })
  }

  deleteNinjs = (id) => {   
    let ninjas =  this.state.ninjas.filter(ninja => ninja.id !== id)
    this.setState({
      ninjas: ninjas
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>My first React app!</h1>
        <p>Welcome :)</p>
        <Ninjas deleteNinjs={this.deleteNinjs} ninjas={this.state.ninjas} />
        {/*passing the func to bind the data from the child component*/}
        <AddNinja addNinja={this.addNinja} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Ninja.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Ninjas = ({ ninjas, deleteNinjs }) => {   

    const ninjaList = ninjas.map(ninja => {
        return ninja.age > 20 ? (
            <div className="ninja" key={ninja.id}>
                <div>Name: {ninja.name}</div>
                <div> Age: {ninja.age}</div>
                <div>Belt: {ninja.belt}</div>                                          
                <button onClick={() => { deleteNinjs(ninja.id) }} >Delete ninja</button>
            </div>
        ) : null;
    });   

    return (
        <div className="ninja-list">
            {ninjaList}
        </div>                  
    )
}

export default Ninjas
```

AddNinja.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddNinja extends Component {

state = {
    name: null,
    age: null,
    belt: null
}

hendleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
}

hendleSubmit = (e) => {       
    debugger
//this is my testing to see if the state exists
    console.log(this.state)
//
// this is what will fix the bug of 2 childs with same key
    if (this.state.id)
        this.setState({
            id: null
        })
//
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addNinja(this.state);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.hendleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" onChange={this.hendleChange} />
                <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
                <input type="text" id="age" onChange={this.hendleChange} />
                <label htmlFor="belt">Belt:</label>
                <input type="text" id="belt" onChange={this.hendleChange} />
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default AddNinja
```

Now I can make myself an easy "life" and bind all the funcs in the HTML to "this". and then I can see in the debugger "this.state".
but I don't understand why the console is printing this not as undefined but as it is. and "if" statement doesn't work when I try to access to id in state.
her is an image of the problem
[image of the debugger in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em9Bh.png)

Answer (score 2):

`this` isn't necessarily `this` in transpiled code. In this case it's likely something like `_this` temporary variable to simulate how lexical `this` behaves in arrow functions.

Check variables in the scope of current function at breakpoint instead of using 'watch' feature.

See also [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51652054/3731501) for the reference.

Comment: so the answer is to upgrade babel to 7? and I tried to check in the console with _this and it did find state. yet the console.log(this.state) will print _this.state. so why this code knows to find the connection? but if statement doesn't. the code works fine only in some cases.

Comment: The answer is to not use `this` in console in this case. *so why this code knows to find the connection?* - the code 'knows' that because Babel replaces `this` in this place with temporary variable like `_this`. This is what linked answer explains. You can check Babel output to understand better what's going on with your code.

Comment: well, I guess you didn't understand my question or I didn't explain myself good.
my goal is to write a code and to be able to debug it in the chrome.
I understand that babel replaces "this" with _this. so what should I do? not write "this" in arrow functions? use "that" "self" trick? I'm an angular dev, so I can use "this" in any case when I use angular, sometimes I need to manual bind. in react, it seems I need to always manual bind. I believe there is a "right" way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked the same question here:

[Chrome, Firefox debuggers not displaying the correct value for 'this' in a react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513424/chrome-firefox-debuggers-not-displaying-the-correct-value-for-this-in-a-react)

Basically the issue is that when you define an class variable arrow function -  (ie. `hendleSubmit = () =>`), this isn't actually valid JavaScript - and there's actually the [transform-class-property babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties) that is running, and binding those functions to the class instance.

My understanding is that when chrome is looking at the sourcemaps to relate it back to your written code - it doesn't see that binding.

The only solution I know of - is to manually bind your class functions like this:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.click2 = this.click2.bind(this);
  }

  click2() {
    console.log(this, "hello");
    let x = 1 + 1;
  }
```