# Refactoring react this binding

Tags: reactjs

I have this code

```js
class BottomPanel extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dropDownUpdate = this.dropDownUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  dropDownUpdate = e => this.setState({ dropDownValue: e.currentTarget.textContent });
```

I was wondering if I can refactor

```js
this.dropDownUpdate = this.dropDownUpdate.bind(this);
```

to

```js
this.dropDownUpdate = this.dropDownUpdate;
```

if so, why or why not? I just saw it somewhere being done this way

```js
this.dropDownUpdate = this.dropDownUpdate;
```

I'm not sure if I can apply it to my code.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yup, I think so far it is working. But, I don't really want to use it unless I understand why.

Comment: doesn;t it work the same without the `this.dropDownUpdate = this.dropDownUpdate.bind(this);` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to be aware of, is that when you write:

```
class BottomPanel extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  dropDownUpdate = e => this.setState({ dropDownValue: e.currentTarget.textContent });
}
```

This (currently) is not valid ES6 syntax. You can't assign a class variable with an equals sign that way. The reason it works is because of the `transform-class-properties` babel plugin, more on that below.

See this question and answer for more details:

[ES6 class variable alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives)

Technically, the right way to declare a class variable is with the `this` keyword like:

```
class BottomPanel extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props) {
      this.dropDownUpdate = this.dropDownUpdate.bind(this)
  }

   dropDownUpdate(e) {
       this.setState({ dropDownValue: e.currentTarget.textContent });
   }
}
```

For why you can't just do:

```
class BottomPanel extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props) {
      this.dropDownUpdate =e => this.setState({ dropDownValue: e.currentTarget.textContent });
  }
}
```

see this post: [Can I use arrow function in constructor of a react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600967/can-i-use-arrow-function-in-constructor-of-a-react-component)

Now the thing is - I assume that you are using Create React App - which comes with the `transform-class-properties` babel plugin - which is why that first declaration works.

Take a look at this question as to why you would want to to the `this.dropDownUpdate = this.dropDownUpdate.bind(this);` trick. It's not necessary - but you run into a debugger issue (the browser not being aware of the `transform-class-properties` babel transform).

[Chrome, Firefox debuggers not displaying the correct value for 'this' in a react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513424/chrome-firefox-debuggers-not-displaying-the-correct-value-for-this-in-a-react)

Otherwise you can just clear your class methods like:

```
class BottomPanel extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  dropDownUpdate = e => this.setState({ dropDownValue: e.currentTarget.textContent });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since dropDownUpdate is an Arrow function, It should work as expected without

`this.dropDownUpdate = this.dropDownUpdate;` Or

`this.dropDownUpdate = this.dropDownUpdate.bind(this);`

In Arrow functions, value of `this` is lexically bound, unlike regular functions where the value of `this` changes based on the context in which the function is called.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600967/can-i-use-arrow-function-in-constructor-of-a-react-component

Comment: Thanks for mentioning! @user1176111 Do checkout the pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your function as below.

dropDownUpdate = (event) => {
....
}

It wont need to bind in constructor

Comment: This only works if you are using the `transfrom-class-properties` babel plugin (which comes with create-react-app)